# How do I make this PHP form with a Google Recaptcha POST to a different URL?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have to create a PHP form with a Google reCaptcha. The form has to POST to a specific URL to process the submission and when the form submits, it can not redirect the user to another page.

I have found the basic example of the form, the java and the PHP code. I need help adding the submission data to a different URL.

How do I make this PHP form, with a Google Recaptcha, POST to a different URL with the reCaptcha still working? I need the form's data to submit to a specific URL which will then process the submissions.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // access
    $secretKey = '___enter_secret_key___';
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please check the the captcha form.</p>';
      exit;
    }

    # FIX: Replace this email with recipient email
    $mail_to = "demo@gmail.com";

    # Sender Data
    $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," ") , strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"])));
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) OR empty($phone) OR empty($subject) OR empty($message)) {
        # Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please complete the form and try again.</p>';
        exit;
    }

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);

    if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
      echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Please check the the captcha form.</p>';
    } else {
        # Mail Content
        $content = "Name: $name\n";
        $content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $content .= "Phone: $phone\n";
        $content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        # email headers.
        $headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        # Send the email.
        $success = mail($mail_to, $subject, $content, $headers);
        if ($success) {
            # Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo '<p class="alert alert-success">Thank You! Your message has been sent.</p>';
        } else {
            # Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">Oops! Something went wrong, we couldnt send your message.</p>';
        }
    }

} else {
    # Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo '<p class="alert alert-warning">There was a problem with your submission, please try again.</p>';
}

 ?>
```

Comment: why not just submit the form to ur submissions processing url and check the captcha there. if its success than save otherwise show some error.

Comment: Thats a great idea. How would I add the validation on the submission page? Would I use the field name?

Comment: which version are you using? v2 recaptcha or v3?

Comment: I am currently using v2

Answer (score 0):

okay, so to simplify the process and remove the middle check, we can do the recatptcha verification and form submissions processing on same file. Use the follwoing php code to verify your captcha result and proceed accordingly.

PHP (Form submissions processing file):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['your_form_submit'])){

  $captcha = $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $handle = curl_init('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY&response=$captcha");
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $response = curl_exec($handle);
  $explodedArr = explode(",",$response);
  $doubleExplodedArr = explode(":",$explodedArr[0]);
  $captchaConfirmation = end($doubleExplodedArr);

  if(trim($captchaConfirmation) == "true") {

    //DO YOUR STUFF HERE TO PROCESS SUBMISSIONS    

  } else {
    echo "<script> alert('Captcha entry was wrong. Please try again') </script>";
  }

} //end
```